# Is there any way to do a complete "factory reset" of mouse drivers on OSX?

Tags: macos, drivers, mouse

After I installed Logitech Mouse drivers on my Macbook Pro 14" (M1), any mouse I connect to OSX is completely weird now. It works, but it feels like it has an acceleration curve that feels completely off. When I do small movements, it is way smaller than it should be. It is very hard to use that mouse on OSX. It works fine on my other Windows notebook. I've uninstalled the drivers but the issue still persists. Is there any way to do a complete factory reset of everything related to mouses on OSX? Drivers, configs, all?

Comment: LG don't make mice, they make televisions, displays etc. Can you link to this mouse & drivers?

Comment: lol, I meant logitech. damn

Comment: Logi Options has a pointer speed, adjustable per app if you need. It doesn't affect the acceleration curve. I see you found SteerMouse for that, which is what I'd have suggested too ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the mouse was somehow having an acceleration, even though I explicitly removed it on the terminal. As suggested on the Apple IRC room on Libera, I installed the SteerMouse app and managed to get rid of it.